# jql information in database

Tags: jira, jql

Here is a jql query that I got the result of

```
assignee in membersOf("project")
```

This would return the issues of members belonging to project.

I would like to know in which table of jira database would this data(or this link of which member belong to which proj) is stored?

Comment: It depends if you are actually talking about group memberships, or project role memberships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Group Membership

The group memberships are stored in the `CWD_MEMBERSHIP` table.

Example:

```
SELECT LOWER_CHILD_NAME 
FROM CWD_MEMBERSHIP 
WHERE MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'GROUP_USER' 
AND LOWER_PARENT_NAME = 'jira-administrators';
```

Example2, to fetch the user infos as well:

```
SELECT
   U.*
FROM
   CWD_MEMBERSHIP M
INNER JOIN CWD_USER U
ON
   M.LOWER_CHILD_NAME = U.LOWER_USER_NAME
WHERE
   M.MEMBERSHIP_TYPE   = 'GROUP_USER' AND
   M.LOWER_PARENT_NAME = 'jira-administrators';
```

### Project Role Membership

The project role memberships however are in the `PROJECTROLE` and `PROJECTROLEACTOR` tables.

Example:

```
SELECT A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER AS USERNAME, R.NAME AS ROLENAME, P.PKEY || ' - ' || P.PNAME AS PROJECTNAME
FROM PROJECTROLEACTOR A
INNER JOIN PROJECTROLE R ON A.PROJECTROLEID = R.ID
INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON A.PID = P.ID
WHERE P.PKEY = 'YOUR_PKEY_COMES_HERE'
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2;
```

Example2, to get users that are explicitly assigned to project roles (not through groups):

```
SELECT A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER AS USERNAME, R.NAME AS ROLENAME, P.PKEY || ' - ' || P.PNAME AS PROJECTNAME
FROM PROJECTROLEACTOR A
INNER JOIN PROJECTROLE R ON A.PROJECTROLEID = R.ID
INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON A.PID = P.ID
INNER JOIN CWD_USER U ON LOWER(A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER) = U.LOWER_USER_NAME
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2;
```

### Issue Change History

To get the issue history, you'll need the `changegroup` and `changeitem` tables joined to `jiraissue`. Changegroup stores who changed and when, changeitem contains the olda and new data, alongside what field was changed.

Example of listing ex-assignees:

```
SELECT
   CG.AUTHOR   AS CHANGE_USER ,
   CG.CREATED  AS CHANGE_WHEN ,
   CI.FIELD    AS CHANGED_WHAT,
   CI.OLDVALUE AS CHANGED_FROM,
   CI.NEWVALUE AS CHANGED_TO
FROM
   JIRAISSUE JI
INNER JOIN CHANGEGROUP CG
ON
   JI.ID = CG.ISSUEID
INNER JOIN CHANGEITEM CI
ON
   CG.ID = CI.GROUPID
WHERE
   JI.PROJECT   = 10100 AND
   JI.ISSUENUM  = 1234 AND
   CI.FIELDTYPE = 'jira' AND
   CI.FIELD     = 'assignee'
ORDER BY
   CG.CREATED ASC;
```

The last row's (newest `created`) `newvalue` must match `jiraissue`.`assignee`-s value.

Comment: Appreciated!. But the case is like there are some members in one project (they can also be assigned with tickets from other projects as well). I am trying to fetch the list of all the issues by members who belong to project(which also counts the issues from other projects).

Comment: To break it down further i am searching for sql equivalent of a jql : assignee in membersOF("project A")

Comment: Hm, a question: what counts as a "member" of a project? developer? project administrator?

Comment: From myunderstandings when we go to profile view of jira we can see an option 'Groups' .But what i observed the same groups an also matches with project name

Comment: Ah, so thats your local setup. Anyways, feel free to transform these queries :-)

Comment: One doubt can't groups names be other than jira-users,jira-*, like somename consisting of members?

Comment: Oh, they can be like anything, but I suggest keep them within the english alphabet + spaces and dashes.

Comment: Work great! Thnx!! :D

Comment: Similar question where would 'assignee was' data be stored.I mean the history of the ticket assignee information.